# is using mutex faster then semaphore in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mutex

My application is very very speed esential and even a microsecond matters.I am using semaphore(1,1) at varios places. I think it can be easily converted into mutex.But I want to know if it will be advantageous or its one and the same thing as far as speed is concerned.
I will be oblidged for any constructive answer.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you optimizing without having searched for and found bottlenecks first? That sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences that may impact performance.
See this similar question for more details:
[What is the difference between semaphore and mutex in implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953496/what-is-the-difference-between-semaphore-and-mutex-in-implementation)