# only one thread may cause deadlock or freezing the program on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, mutex, deadlock

I am doing C++ multithread programming. I use mutex to read and write a queue in order to avoid deadlock. Currently, I only launch 1 thread for

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex);
```

But, in GDB, my code is frozen here, it is pending.

Why ?  there is only one thread !!!

thanks

Comment: How do you initialize the mutex?

Comment: I use pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) inside a class contr.

Comment: Since you seem to assume that "the thread that locked it already can lock it again" you may be looking for _recursive mutexes_ (`PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE`). Regarding that, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187761/recursive-lock-mutex-vs-non-recursive-lock-mutex/1244997#1244997 - generally, it's possible to achieve this behaviour. But recursive locking also tends to allow for subtle bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`pthread_mutex_lock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) manual page:

> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL, deadlock detection shall
>   not be provided. Attempting to relock the mutex causes deadlock. If a
>   thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex
>   which is unlocked, undefined behavior results.
>
> If the mutex type is PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT, attempting to recursively
>   lock the mutex results in undefined behavior. Attempting to unlock the
>   mutex if it was not locked by the calling thread results in undefined
>   behavior. Attempting to unlock the mutex if it is not locked results
>   in undefined behavior.

Bottom line: it's perfectly possible to cause a deadlock with only one thread if you try to lock a mutex that is already locked.

In case you are wondering, on Linux `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT` is usually a synonym of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL`, which in turn is what is used in the default mutex initializer.