# deadlock in a single process -?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, deadlock

Can the condition when single process/thread is blocked trying to acquire the same mutex be called "deadlock"?

mutex_lock(&mutex) - success
...
mutex_lock(&mutex) - blocked, mutex not released

Seems as condition of "nonshearable resource" doesn't apply: here is only single process/thread so that no case of nonshearable resource 
hold and wait: here is only single process so that no wait for another process to release the requested resource

Comment: With a [recursive mutex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/187761/60761) the problem would not occur. Without  it it's just an error in the algorithm.

Comment: Absolutely... i am just wondering about apparent formal discrepancies with Colleman's "4 neccessary conditions of deadlock":   
   2. Hold and Wait or Resource Holding: A process is currently holding at least one resource and requesting additional resources which are being held by other processes - no other processes in this case

Comment: Your thread is requesting a resource that is already held by a  thread. That it's the same thread does not matter, just peculiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, that is considered, or would potentially* result in deadlock.

the term is not bound to threads or processes - but *requests*.

suppose your lock (`mutex`) is *not* reentrant, and suppose your resource is locked when mutated, and that it is an error to mutate the resource from multiple sources. what happens when/if your single threaded process attempts to initiate a new mutation of the data within a mutation and the non-reentrant lock which is locked is requested to lock? deadlock

'potentially', because you have not specified exactly what type of mutex you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a Deadlock.

***Deadlock*** can arise if four conditions hold simultaneously.

- **Mutual exclusion**: The resources involved must be unshareable; otherwise, the processes would not be prevented from using the resource when necessary. Only one process can use the resource at any given instant of time.
- **Hold and wait or resource holding**: a process is currently holding at least one resource and requesting additional resources which are being held by other processes.
- **No preemption**: a resource can be released only voluntarily by the process holding it.
- **Circular wait**: each process must be waiting for a resource which is being held by another process, which in turn is waiting for the first process to release the resource. In general, there is a set of waiting processes, P = {P1, P2, …, PN}, such that P1 is waiting for a resource held by P2, P2 is waiting for a resource held by P3 and so on until PN is waiting for a resource held by P1.

[more...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)

With a *single process*, the *Circular Wait* condition can never be met, thus *deadlock* can never arise with a *single process*.