# Ensure that a thread doesn't lock a mutex twice?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, deadlock

Say I have a thread running a member method like `runController` in the example below:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass() { 
         // Start controller thread
         mControllerThread = std::thread(&SomeClass::runController, this) 
    }

    ~SomeClass() {
         // Stop controller thread
         mIsControllerThreadInterrupted = true;
         // wait for thread to die.
         std::unique_lock<std:::mutex> lk(mControllerThreadAlive); 
    }

    // Both controller and external client threads might call this
    void modifyObject() {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mObjectMutex);
         mObject.doSomeModification();
    }
    //...
private:
    std::mutex mObjectMutex;
    Object mObject;

    std::thread mControllerThread;
    std::atomic<bool> mIsControllerInterrupted;
    std::mutex mControllerThreadAlive;

    void runController() {        
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> aliveLock(mControllerThreadAlive);
        while(!mIsControllerInterruped) {
            // Say I need to synchronize on mObject for all of these calls
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mObjectMutex);
            someMethodA();
            modifyObject(); // but calling modifyObject will then lock mutex twice
            someMethodC();
        }
    }
    //...
};
```

And some (or all) of the subroutines in `runController` need to modify data that is shared between threads and guarded by a mutex. Some (or all) of them, might also be called by other threads that need to modify this shared data.

With all the glory of C++11 at my disposal, how can I ensure that no thread ever locks a mutex twice?

Right now, I'm passing `unique_lock` references into the methods as parameters as below. But this seems clunky, difficult to maintain, potentially disastrous, etc...

```
void modifyObject(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& objectLock) {

    // We don't even know if this lock manages the right mutex... 
    // so let's waste some time checking that.
    if(objectLock.mutex() != &mObjectMutex)
         throw std::logic_error();

    // Lock mutex if not locked by this thread
    bool wasObjectLockOwned = objectLock.owns_lock();
    if(!wasObjectLockOwned)
        objectLock.lock();

    mObject.doSomeModification();

    // restore previous lock state
    if(!wasObjectLockOwned)
        objectLock.unlock();

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am a little confused. Do you have unchecked `try_to_lock`s? How can a thread lock a mutex and then forget about it?

Comment: I don't understand the nature of the problem. You lock the mutex right before reading or modifying shared data, and unlock right after. You would normally have an instance of `unique_lock` on the stack, not passed in as a parameter. You must be doing something quite unorthodox if locking the same mutex twice is an actual risk in your design. Can you show exactly how this may happen for you?

Comment: @RedAlert Ah, perhaps `std::try_to_lock` is the answer I was looking for? Can I just call that from every function that needs a lock instead of creating a local `unique_lock` or passing locks around?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I updated the question with a more explicit example, but let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @mxdubois no, then you'd lose mutual exclusion with other threads. You need to resolve this at the design level. In your example, a good fix would be to completely remove mutexes from `modifyObject()`, and instead have only the functions that call it handle the access to the shared resource.

Comment: Use a recursive mutex and avoid the whole problem. Just use 'Resource Acquisition Is Initialization' to acquire/release the `unique_lock` as an object on the stack.

Comment: @EJP [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/187761/1599617) leads me to believe that it's cleaner to avoid recursive mutexes if possible. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: What's the point of `mControllerThreadAlive`? Do you have something against [`std::thread::join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)?

Comment: @Casey Oh yeah... it doesn't make sense in the example, but in my project I want to be able to check if the thread is still alive without ending it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways to avoid this kind of programming error. I recommend doing it on a class design level:

- separate between *public* and *private* member functions,
- only *public* member functions lock the *mutex*,
- and *public* member functions are never called by other member functions.

If a function is needed both internally and externally, create two variants of the function, and delegate from one to the other:

```
public:
    // intended to be used from the outside
    int foobar(int x, int y)
    {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mControllerThreadAlive);
         return _foobar(x, y);
    }
private:
    // intended to be used from other (public or private) member functions
    int _foobar(int x, int y)
    {
        // ... code that requires locking
    }
```

Comment: And then there are class private methods that you bind to `this` and pass along as callbacks. Then you don't know whether that method should be prefixed by an underscore as all the other private methods, or not. It gets messy.