# Acquire a read/write lock if not already held

Tags: multithreading, glib

In GLib, is there an operation to tell it “acquire the lock if you don’t hold it already”? Can the same thread acquire a lock twice (making the second acquisition a no-op, or requiring it to be released twice) or test if it is already holding a particular lock?

Suppose I have the following functions in my code:

```
void func_a() {
    //g_rw_lock_writer_lock(&shared_data->rw_lock);
    mess_with_data(shared_data);
    func_b();
    //g_rw_lock_writer_unlock(&shared_data->rw_lock);
}

void func_b() {
    //g_rw_lock_writer_lock(&shared_data->rw_lock);
    mess_with_data_again(shared_data);
    //g_rw_lock_writer_unlock(&shared_data->rw_lock);
}
```

Assume that:

- `shared_data` points to a shared data structure, and access needs to be synchronized between threads
- `shared_data->rw_lock` is the read/write lock to synchronize access
- Both `func_a()` and `func_b()` can be called from outside
- `mess_with_data()` and `mess_with_data_again()` are not thread-safe, thus the caller needs to hold a write lock on the data before calling them
- They are not just single function calls but rows of statements, so copying the body of `func_b()` into `func_a()` is not an option (code duplication, poor maintainability)
- The callers of `func_a()` and `func_b()` have no direct access to the lock, therefore locking needs to happen under the hood
- Extracting the function body of `func_b()` (sans the locking/unlocking) into a separate helper function called by both `func_a()` and `func_()` is not an option (they are spread out across multiple modules and there are layers of abstraction between the function calls—in fact, `func_a()` does not directly call `func_b()` by name but a pointer which happens to resolve to `func_b()`).

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: the word you're looking for is "[recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187761/recursive-lock-mutex-vs-non-recursive-lock-mutex)".

While `GMutex` explicitly mentions that whether or not the mutex is recursive is undefined, AFAIK `GRWLock` just omits any mention for whether the *writer* lock is recursive (the reader side is recursive).

If you dive into the implementation a bit, you'll see that on POSIX `GRWLock` is implemented using a `pthread_rwlock_t`, [which needn't be recursive](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_rwlock_wrlock.html) ("Results are undefined if the calling thread holds the read-write lock (whether a read or write lock) at the time the call is made.").  So basically no, `GRWLock` isn't recursive for writer locks.

As for how to solve your problem, my first suggestion would be to have  `mess_with_data` and `mess_with_data_again` acquire and release the lock themselves.  Remember, you should only hold locks for as long as necessary and no longer.

If that's not an option for some reason (like maybe you don't have access to that code), you could use a lock that is recursive, or restrict writer operations to one thread and use a queue to communicate with it.

It may also be possible to refactor `mess_with_data` and `mess_with_data_again` so they don't require locks, but that may or may not be possible and would likely be quite difficult.